# How to set Frequency at 4 specific hours everyday

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scheduler

Do you know if I can specify 4 (or more) specific times to run a job every day for a scheduler in google cloud console ?

I would like to avoid to replicate the job 4 times with 4 different hours.

I have tried something like

```
* 9 * * *, * 12 * * *
```

(separated by a comma) and so on...

I couldn't find my case in the documentation...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys, I found out. I don't know where I can find explanation for what can be called *scheduler language* but let's say you want to start a scheduler job in google cloud platform at **9, 10, 11 AM every day** you should just write :

```
0 9,10,11 * * *
```

Comment: The official documentation is https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html but there are much better sites for understanding the crontab entries

Comment: Thank you very much. I meant in the Google documentation, I didn't see crontab references that would have help me 

Comment: For the most part, Google does not need to document OS or application features unless required. That could create a documentation nightmare and increase customer costs. Google offers Cloud Scheduler, so they document the crontab format they implement: https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules Note: Cloud Scheduler is similar to, but not the same as Unix/Linux cron.